# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "djstripe_coupon" already exists

Tags: django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I am making an app for subscription using dj-stripe and DRF. when make a POST request 127.0.0.1:8000/subscription/subscription-success/?session_id={session_id}
i got this error:

`return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "subscription_subscription" does not exist LINE 1: ...an_id", "subscription_subscription"."status" FROM "subscript...`

I tried to solve the problem with rum python manage.py migrate, but got this

```bash
python manage.py migrate
INFO:VectorDB:Loading the weights for the embedding model. This may take a few seconds the first time it runs because it downloads the weights and caches them.
INFO:VectorDB:Loading the weights has been completed in 0.14159846305847168 seconds
System check identified some issues:

INFOS:
?: (djstripe.I001) You don't have any API Keys in the database. Did you forget to add them?
    HINT: Add STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY and STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY directly from the Django Admin.
?: (djstripe.I002) Your keys are defined in the settings files. You can now add and manage them directly from the django admin.
    HINT: Add STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY and STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY directly from the Django Admin.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, djstripe, schema, sessions, subscription, vectordb
Running migrations:
  Applying djstripe.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "djstripe_coupon" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 447, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "djstripe_coupon" already exists
```

I dropped all tables of dj-stripe in database, and the new error is:

```
raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin) 
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration djstripe.0013_merge_20231127_1940 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('djstripe', '0012_2_8')
```

How solve the migrations issues? I use Postgress as default database